# What is the most efficient way to search multiple times in a large database MySQL

Tags: mysql, performance, large-data, bigdata

I have GEO ip location database where each countriy has a range of IP associated with it.

```
country | ip_start | ip_end
```

I have a very large list of ip (1 million) and i need to associate each ip to the right country by looking up in the geo_database.

i currently use this inefficient query (Python btw):

```
"SELECT * FROM geoipv4_country WHERE %s BETWEEN start_integer AND end_integer" % myDict[ipnum]"
```

As you can see by doing this for every ip in my list it will take HUGE amount of time because for every ip i need to query the DB.

Is there a good efficient way of doing this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

First, create some table that will contain your large list of IP addresses:

```
CREATE TABLE ip_list (
    ipnum INTEGER
);
INSERT INTO ip_list (ipnum) VALUES
    (<ip1>), (<ip2>), (<ip3>), (<ip4>), ..., (<ipN>);
```

Then, you can get your list using query like this:

```
SELECT i.ipnum, c.country
FROM geoipv4_country с,
     ip_list         i
WHERE i.ipnum BETWEEN c.start_integer
                  AND c.end_integer
```

This assumes that ranges in `geoipv4_country` table cannot overlap.

To make it efficient, be sure to have at least following indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX c1 ON geoipv4_country(start_integer);
CREATE INDEX c2 ON geoipv4_country(end_integer);
```

Comment: You 10 lines of SQL will replace my 60 of python! thanks i'll give it a try!